# How do i see "INSERT" Transaction log in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I am trying to find out how does my script from another system insert into the database as it takes 30 minutes, way too long. I want to see how every record in which period is being inserted.

The database server has multiple database and each database has multiple tables.
If I only want to see INSERT record in a database called `PB_IG` and table name `ecmpb.CHAR_VALUE`, what should I do?

Comment: use sql server profiler and filter text with "Pg_IG"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run your `sql server profiler`, go to `"New Trace" -> "Event Selections"` tab, and filter your trace `textdata` property

[image]

Comment: How do you open that?
I am at SQL Server profiler and couldnt find that screen.

Comment: New trace, then Event Selections Tab